# how to launch event from a textbox even when the field is empty c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I get data from the data base then i show it in a datagrid (wpf) , the user can make quick search (filter) from a textbox after clicking on Enter.
I use this event to handle the button -Enter- click 
(OnSearch - This event is spawn whenever the search button is clicked or the Enter key is pressed.)

the problem is when the user don't write anything, the event will not be launched even when he click on Enter-Button !
how can i proceed to make it work

```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       //m_txtTest is a SearchTextBox
       m_txtTest.OnSearch += new RoutedEventHandler(m_txtTest_OnSearch);    
   }

   void m_txtTest_OnSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      //to get the entered string
      SearchEventArgs searchArgs = e as SearchEventArgs;
      ....
      ....
      ....
      ....
   }
```

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML. Otherwise no one will be able to help you just by guessing.

Comment: _the problem is when the user don't write anything, the event will not be launched even when he click on Enter-Button_. Isn't this good behavior? [Usually empty boxes don't search](http://www.google.com)

Comment: indeed , i need to reinitialize the search result when the entered Text is empty

Answer (score 0):

So when your user types something in and presses enter it is the textbox handling the Event.

When they don't type anything though the textbox doesn't have focus and cant handle the event.

What I would do is create an event for searching on the window or grid.

Somthing like this

```
this.OnPreviewKeyDown += new OnPreviewKeyDownEvent;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx

You can think of it like this

> Window has focus
>
> ->Grid has focus
>
> -->textbox has focus

What ever the last thing that has focus (or the most inner element, think of it like a cake) is will be the thing that sees the event first. If you have that event registered for that UI element it will handle it.

The textbox isn't focused so it wont see the event